# Android the getDrawingCache() not contain actual values from TextView/TextClock

Tags: android, bitmap, drawingcache

I would like to get two bitmaps of screen. Problem is, `TextView` or `TextClock` contains values from first call of `getDrawingCache()`. Values for `TextView` or `TextClock` are not refreshed in new `Bitmap` after second call of `getDrawingCache()`.

Work on Nexus 5 (second bitmap contains correct time from `TextClock`).
On many other devices not work. E.g.: Huawei Honor 4C.

```
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 25
compileSdkVersion 25
```

`TextClock` automatically changes value. Not working even though i call `setText()` method on `TextView`.
Where is problem?

Test:
Create simple layout with: `TextClock` and run this code in UI Thread:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.i("TAG", Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try {
            Bitmap bitmapScreen = getBitmapOfScreen();
            //File f = new File("/storage/sdcard1", "tmp.jpg");   //Huawei
            File f = new File("/storage/emulated/0", "tmp.jpg");  //Nexus 5
            FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream(f);
            bitmapScreen.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fis);
            fis.flush();
            fis.close();
            bitmapScreen.recycle();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}, 5000);

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.i("TAG", Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try {
            Bitmap bitmapScreen = getBitmapOfScreen();
            //File f = new File("/storage/sdcard1", "tmp2.jpg");    //Huawei
            File f = new File("/storage/emulated/0", "tmp2.jpg");  //Nexus 5
            FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream(f);
            bitmapScreen.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fis);
            fis.flush();
            fis.close();
            bitmapScreen.recycle();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}, 10000);

/** Must be called in UI thread.*/
public Bitmap getBitmapOfScreen() throws Exception {

    final View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
    v1.destroyDrawingCache();
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    v1.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
    bitmap.setHasAlpha(true);           //important for PNG
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: post getBitmapOfScreen() method

Comment: There is. Scroll down.

Comment: try to add v1.buildDrawingCache() before creating bitmap from getdrawingcache

Comment: Not solved. Bitmap still contains same value from TextClock view.

Comment: then add v1.destroyDrawingCache(); before v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

Comment: Still not solved :| Code updated by your advices. Thank you.
But i am trying textClock.invalidate(); and maybe it works. Moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved.**

Missing called `invalidate()` on view. For now, when i call `invalidate()` on `TextClock` before `getBitmapOfScreen()` call, value is correct in bitmap.